# How to find efficiently the independent vertex sets from a large adjacency matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, partitions, graphs-and-networks

I have a binary adjacency matrix $M$ of size $72\times 72$. I would like to find all possible combinations of 18 non-adjacent nodes.

There are $^{72}C_{18}$ possible (adjacent and non-adjacenct) combinations.
I want to find all valid combinations.

You can try the adjacency matrix at: [How to color nodes in a adjacency graph with different colors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/187262/how-to-color-nodes-in-a-adjacency-graph-with-different-colors)

If one particular node is in a valid combination, then its adjacent nodes cannot be part of that valid combination.

I am using the following code.

```
    all = FindIndependentVertexSet[AdjacencyGraph@M, {18, Infinity}, All];
    Union @ Catenate @ Map[Subsets[#, {18}]&] @ all
```

The Mathematica kernel keep running........

Is it possible to find them in an efficient manner.

Comment: @Szabolcs, can IGraph/M handle this?

Comment: This is not a reasonable request. How many do you expect there to be? Have you made an estimate?  Do you expect to even be able to store all of them in memory?

Comment: I did not see your question. Yes, IGraph/M can find cliques or independent vertex sets that are not maximal (something Mma's builtin does not do). The clique finder in particular is faster than Mathematica's, in some cases *much* faster. The independent vertex sets of a graph are the same as the cliques of its complement. So you can try that, for smaller graphs.

Comment: However, your graph may have many more of these than what is reasonable to compute.

Comment: @Szabolcs, can you give me the code to do this? IGIndependentVertexSets[AdjacencyGraph@M, {18}] will not do the job?

Comment: As I said, try to find the cliques of the complement. For example, `g = GraphComplement@IGTriangularLattice[10];
IGCliqueSizeCounts[g, {10}]` counts cliques of size 10 in an 55-vertex graph, and you *could* retrieve them with `IGCliques`, but there are 126 million in total ... But your graph is likely simply too large for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** This is not a reasonable thing to try to compute. The problem is too large. Try to estimate the size of the solution before you proceed.

---

The graph you posted in your last question was very sparse (based on a triangular grid). An empty graph on 72 nodes would have

```
Binomial[72, 18]
(* 41432089765583440 *)
```

independent vertex sets.  Yours will have fewer, but not by many orders fewer.

---

IGraph/M has a very fast clique finder, which can be used to find independent vertex sets.  Recall that the independent vertex sets of a graph are the cliques of its complement.

Let's try to do what you are asking for a smaller triangular lattice.

```
g = GraphComplement@IGTriangularLattice[10];
cl = IGCliqueSizeCounts[g, {10}]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 126138885} *)
```

This will only *count* the cliques. It will not store them. There are $126\,138\,885$ independent vertex sets of size 10 in this graph of 55 vertices, considerably smaller than yours.

This would take *more* than

```
126138885*10*8/1024.^3
(* 9.39808 *)
```

gigabytes of memory even in the most optimistic case of having everything as packed arrays.

When I tried to retrieve these in practice, the Mathematica kernel ended up using a maximum of 38 gigabytes of memory.

Your problem is *much* larger.  It won't be possible to store all these cliques.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't get where/how have you defined the graph with 55 vertices?

Comment: @dipaknarayanan I used `IGTriangularLattice[10]` as an example. It has 55 vertices.