# Vertex-coloring a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am seeking the equivalent of
[`MinimumVertexColoring[g]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/MinimumVertexColoring.html) in Mathematica 12.
I've been unsuccessful with either of these options to access old code:

```
<< Combinatorica`
<< IGraphM`
```

Comment: Your question is either a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189181/9490), or you need to add more information as to why it is different.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks, I found that answer earlier. First, I don't need the chromatic polynomial, I need actual vertex color assignments.  But second, I cannot load the packages described in that answer. Maybe that's just my ignorance: Get::noopen: Cannot open IGraphM`.

Comment: @JasonB. Oh, I see, needed to download the package. Got it! I will delete this question after a while.

Comment: see also: [How to color nodes in a adjacency graph with different colors?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/187262/125)

Comment: External packages, written by the community, are very powerful, but definitely not as easy to find as they should be.  If you find `IGraphM` to be useful, give kudos to Szabolcs.

Comment: I'll leave this up for the useful links. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke IGraph/M is not a built-in package that ships with Mathematica. It is a separate package that I created myself. You will find the installation instructions here: https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IGraph/M has extensive and very fast graph colouring functionality (both exact and approximate), but it is not API-compatible with the now deprecated Combinatorica. In other words, loading `` <<IGraphM` ``  is not going to make old Combinatorica code work without modifications. The modifications are worth it though as IGraph/M is much, much faster, and works with Mathematica's `Graph` data structure directly.

You will find many graph colouring examples in [the IGraph/M documentation](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#graph-colouring).

A small example:

```
Nest[IGMycielskian, CycleGraph[4], 2] // (* Mycielski construction increase the chromatic number *)
 Graph[#, VertexSize -> Large, GraphStyle -> "BasicBlack"] & // (* styling: large vertices, black edges *)
 IGVertexMap[ColorData[97], VertexStyle -> IGMinimumVertexColoring] (* style graph based on vertex colouring *)
```

[image]

The available functions are

- `IGVertexColoring`, `IGEdgeColoring` for fast heuristic colouring (not exact minimum).
- `IGKVertexColoring`, `IGKEdgeColoring` finds a colouring with no more than $k$ colours
- `IGMinimumVertexColoring`, `IGMinimumEdgeColoring` find a minimum colouring, and have performance that is competitive with the best you might find elsewhere.
- `IGChromaticNumber`, `IGChromaticIndex` just compute the minimum number of required colours.

Comment: Thanks! I am already using it.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Feedback is always welcome (feel free to email).